# Reporting services - Interactive sort nulls last - Reportviewer VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sorting, dynamic, reporting-services

SSRS 2008

I've defined Interactive sort on a column that has also null values.

I want the nulls to **always** appear at the **end** of the report regardless of whether the
direction is **Ascending or Descending**.

Report is displayed by Reportviewer in VS2010

User clicks on column header to activate interactive sort

All help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one workaround here, which may or may not help, but at worst might give you more ideas.

What you can try doing is actually use two tables, and apply the sort to only one, but make it look like one table in the report.

**Create two tables:**

[image]

[image]

**Apply filters to the tables to show non-null values in the first and null values in the second.**

[image]

I used the expression:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!val2.Value), "NULL", "NOTNULL")
```

**Apply Interactive Sorting to the first table.**

This gives the results:

[image]

[image]

So in this simple case it's achieving what you're after.

Since it's actually two objects, you might get breaks in places users don't expect; this could be mitigated by keeping the objects together with a **Rectangle**.

If you're looking for multiple columns this might not be suitable, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Very interesting answer - Thanks - will try along those lines (two tables)

Comment: Good luck. As above, it probably depends on your data to see how suitable it is; but there are always various workarounds to try. Let me know how it goes.